# Efficient Kronecker product with identity matrix and regular matrix - NumPy/ Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I am working on a python project and making use of numpy. I frequently have to compute Kronecker products of matrices by the identity matrix. These are a pretty big bottleneck in my code so I would like to optimize them. There are two kinds of products I have to take. The first one is:

```
np.kron(np.eye(N), A)
```

This one is pretty easy to optimize by simply using [scipy.linalg.block_diag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html). The product is equivalent to:

```
la.block_diag(*[A]*N)
```

Which is about 10 times faster. However, I am unsure on how to optimize the second kind of product:

```
np.kron(A, np.eye(N))
```

Is there a similar trick I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to initialize an output array of `4D` and then assign values into it from `A`. Such an assignment would broadcast values and this is where we would get efficiency in NumPy.

Thus, a solution would be like so -

```
# Get shape of A
m,n = A.shape

# Initialize output array as 4D
out = np.zeros((m,N,n,N))

# Get range array for indexing into the second and fourth axes 
r = np.arange(N)

# Index into the second and fourth axes and selecting all elements along
# the rest to assign values from A. The values are broadcasted.
out[:,r,:,r] = A

# Finally reshape back to 2D
out.shape = (m*N,n*N)
```

Put as a function -

```
def kron_A_N(A, N):  # Simulates np.kron(A, np.eye(N))
    m,n = A.shape
    out = np.zeros((m,N,n,N),dtype=A.dtype)
    r = np.arange(N)
    out[:,r,:,r] = A
    out.shape = (m*N,n*N)
    return out
```

To simulate `np.kron(np.eye(N), A)`, simply swap the operations along the first and second and similarly for third and fourth axes -

```
def kron_N_A(A, N):  # Simulates np.kron(np.eye(N), A)
    m,n = A.shape
    out = np.zeros((N,m,N,n),dtype=A.dtype)
    r = np.arange(N)
    out[r,:,r,:] = A
    out.shape = (m*N,n*N)
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [174]: N = 100
     ...: A = np.random.rand(100,100)
     ...: 

In [175]: np.allclose(np.kron(A, np.eye(N)), kron_A_N(A,N))
Out[175]: True

In [176]: %timeit np.kron(A, np.eye(N))
1 loops, best of 3: 458 ms per loop

In [177]: %timeit kron_A_N(A, N)
10 loops, best of 3: 58.4 ms per loop

In [178]: 458/58.4
Out[178]: 7.842465753424658
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, of course! For reference, this gives a 6-7x speedup in my tests.

Comment: @user3930598 Good to know! Added mine. Seems about there as well.